# Mercurial: how can I split a single branch into two without losing history?

Tags: mercurial, branch

I have a mercurial repository with a default branch containing two directories at the top level: "demo/" and "product/". I want to do the following, retaining change history if possible:

1) Put everything in "demo/" into a new demo branch. All the files under demo/ would be moved one level down in this new branch, and no demo/ folder would exist in either the default or demo branch.

2) Move everything in "product/" one level down in the default branch, and remove the product/ directory.

The second part seems simple enough and can be done with simply "hg mv" on all files and folders stored in product/ to one level below. So I think that will work as long as hg mv handles the fact that the path for all files in the product/ directory tree change.

The first issue is what I'm having trouble with. Specifically, how to do without losing all the history of files contained in demo/. After some reading, hg rebase doesn't seem like a solution. There's a ton of history here (this repository was originally CVS, then migrated to SVN, now is in Mercurial). I searched for solutions to this issue and all of them focused on moving entire changesets to a different branch, which is not what I desire. What would be the best approach for me to take here?

Comment: After creating the new branch I incorrectly thought that the history was not saved as it was not shown in my repository. But using the `hg log --follow command` I found that the history was indeed retained.

Comment: Alarm! Monkey with grenade! You must to read ABC in order to understand basic concept and principles (of SCM in common), now you show "tabula rasa" in core. BTW, your task is incorrect and can't be solved IN COMMON CASE (only under some special /have to be verified/ conditions)!!! But I'm too lazy to explain "why?" (obvious for skilled techs things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, this would take 3 steps.

Step 1

- in the `default` branch
- move "product/"
- commit (**commit A**)

Step 2

- still in the `default` branch
- move "demo/"
- merge or create `demo` branch **(commit B**)

Step 3

- update to **commit A** (should be back in the `default` branch)
- remove "demo/"
- commit (**commit C**)

Comment: I failed to mention that there are files of the same name in both product/ and game/, so I can not move both directories down in the same branch like that. I used your suggestions to try a test tonight to see if I could make my demo branch retain all the history (but didn't change the default branch since I'm waiting on some merges to happen there before I do anything).

Comment: What I tried tonight was:
* `hg branch demo`
* `hg remove product`
* `hg move demo/* .`
* `hg commit`
* `hg push --newbranch`

This kept none of the history was retained for the files in the demo/ directory and only shows a single commit, which is precisely what I did not want to happen. I don't think that doing the move of demo/ in the default branch before the creation of the demo branch will retain that history.